# Java Tools for combining runtime execution with coverage

Tags: java, eclipse, testing

Are there any free tools for Java (preferably Eclipse) that can give metrics on both how frequently code is executed (based on a recorded run) and do a side by side with coverage? I'm not sure if there is already a metric for measuring this but it seems it would be an interesting one to see.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean running the application as in production ?
if in dev environ ...not sure if this is what you are looking for - http://insectj.sourceforge.net/

Comment: also, I did mean in the dev environment. sorry forgot to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a Java profiler (something that gives you function call counts and elapsed execution times)?  If so, you might want to look at the [Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html).  It doesn't look like it will give you a side-by-side comparison of two pieces of code, but it might be worth looking at.

Comment: I've used TPTP before as well. One of things I guess I'm really looking for is a useful way to combine these metrics - maybe I can invent one.

Answer (score 0):

The [SD Java Profiler](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Profilers/JavaProfiler.html) collects profiling data in a way that generalizes test coverage.  So if you have its profile data displayed, you have the test coverage data effectively displayed too; there's no need for a side-by-side comparison.

Not free, and doesn't plug into eclipse yet, but does use a Java GUI.